# computing bayes factor to test if data supports model

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem, empirical-bayes

Number of customers who attend 2 shops in a 10 minute interval follows a poisson distribution. for the first and second office $y_1=3$ and $y_2=5$

we want to test if we can assume the same average for both shops or different averages. our two models are:

M1:
$y_1$|$\lambda$~ $Po(\lambda)$

$y_2$|$\lambda$~$Po(\lambda)$

$\lambda$~Gamma(2,1)

M2

$y_1|\lambda_1$~Po$(\lambda_1)$

$y_2|\lambda_2$~Po($\lambda_2$)

$\lambda_1$~Gamma(2,1)

$\lambda_2$~Gamma(4,1)

compute the bayes factor in order to test id data supports model 1 or model 2. Ive used the bayes factor formula and I think ive found the numerator but the denominator is in terms of 2 parameters so im struggling to understand how to approach it, would it be integrate twice with respect to $\lambda_1$ and then $\lambda_2$?

Comment: Are the rates in terms of /minute, or is it /(10 minutes)?

Comment: @Paul this is how the question was worded, and what do you mean rates, y1 and y2?

Comment: What are $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: @Paul data collected after the shops where observed in a typical day,  I am assuming y1 is the number of customers observed in shop 1 and y2 for shop 2.